# How can I change the display name in my StackExchange account?

Tags: support, flair, display-names, combined-flair

I ask because I changed my display name in all the accounts I have on the stackexchange network but I couldn't change it in the stackexchange (main) account.

As a result my flair (global) still retains the old display name (I suppose it is linked to the stackexchange account) while I would want it to display my current name:

[image: profile for Ioan Paul Pirau on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Is this at all possible ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you change all of the usernames manually, without using the synchronization mechanism?

If so, try this:

- Go to your account page
- Click the "Accounts" tab
- Scroll to the very bottom
- Click the "Copy [site] profile to all Stack Exchange sites"

[image: Delegate account change synching to the unicorns]

EDIT:

Actually, upon looking at [your Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/bc4e8ca1-4b9e-48cc-8ac5-f5a31541395c), I see that the name change is in effect (unless you just did that right now with synching) - it might be that the flair is cached, or updates delayed - someone else might be able to confirm that.

If you look at the source of the flair image, you can see that in the alt text your updated name is pulled through; the image itself must be cached somewhere, I think.

Comment: First of all.. thank you, that did the trick in changing the display name for my StackExchange account (+1 for that). But the flair remained the same.. this means that my assumption that the **combined flair** is connected to that account is wrong.

Comment: It is maybe also important to note that both flairs (local and combined) in StackOverflow show the old **display name**, while in the other sites the local flair shows the updated display name, and the combined flair still shows the old ID. This is indeed a different problem and I will accept your answer but do you have any ideea why the flair did not update ?

Comment: Yes, I have been made aware that the image is indeed cached - also, Kevin, among others, confirm this.

Answer (score 8):

Flair is cached for a while.  The name portion I believe is cached for 24 hours, the profile picture for a week.

Just give it time and it will sync up.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. (+1)