# How do I change the display name for my Stack Exchange Network profile?

Tags: support, user-accounts, network-profile

Is it possible to change the "user2612587" display name and also change the picture for the Stack Exchange Network profile, like on all the other sites on the network? Or is the Stack Exchange account a generic one that can't be changed?

There are a few questions and answers about changing the display name but I don't think it addresses this particular question. Because the answers to those questions are usually about the synchronization mechanism.

For example, I saw [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104067/152859):

> Did you change all of the display names manually, without using the
>   synchronization mechanism? If so, try this:
>
> 1. Go to your account page
> 2. Click the "Accounts" tab
> 3. Scroll to the very bottom
> 4. Click the "Copy [site] profile to all Stack Exchange sites"

I have tried this, but in my case that option isn't showing up.

> [image: option_NA]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203764/changing-stack-exchange-username

Comment: [According to what I see](http://stackexchange.com/users/1949626/eduardo-dennis), you've already changed your display name, did you not?

Comment: You didn't complete the instructions for account merging - the [user2612587 profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2612587/user2612587) doesn't have the "merge delete" in it. Have you used the "contact us" form as well? I don't expect this to change until the accounts have been merged (which will not happen until you follow through).

Comment: What is the link to the Q&A you are referring to here? I know it's been a while since you posted this. But if you can, please do post a link, it will serve as a reference for future visitors.

Comment: @Sammy it's not a Q&A site but rather the network profile itself. [This is yours](http://stackexchange.com/users/1528948/sammy), for example. :)

Comment: @michaelb958 There is no need to be rude in edit comments! That space is reserved for commenting the changes you make, not for commenting on the incompetence of the previous editor. You could have just added "blockquote". That's 10 characters and enough for edit comment. I do know how to blockquote. The problem was that the text was wrapping, so the step by step list was lost. That's why I used code markup to keep the layout. But I see you have added an extra cr/lf character right before the list. That's why it works now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand that. But I think he was referring to some Q&A here on SO meta. It's hard to know when he forgot to post a link. Those instructions are hardly to be found on the network site.

Comment: @Sammy you mean the post where he took the quote from? I just added the missing link.

Comment: I don't see that option either. It has probably been changed since those instructions were originally posted.

Comment: @Sammy Yeah, that edit comment may have been a little harsh. Misuse of four-space code formatting for stuff that doesn't need it is one of my pet hates; I probably overreacted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, that seems to be about right. Thanks!

Comment: @michaelb958 I can see that. But I forgive you. Friends? :) I'm not really fond of using four-space code formatting either on stuff that doesn't need it. I only use it when I see no other option. But we're all good now. And Wizard has added the missing link. Cheers!

Comment: @Sammy I like it when everything works out fine like this.

Answer (score 3):

> where is the option to change the user2612587 value and upload a picture like all the other sites on the stack exchange network?

There isn't one. It is taken from the profile on the site that you have most reputation on.

Comment: It says "Sync with **oldest** profile" at the bottom of the "About me", is that wrong, or unrelated? And what about ties?

Comment: Indeed, @Dukeling, for me it even says *"Sync with oldest profile **(Stack Overflow)**. Last sync 0s ago."*, where indeed Stack Overflow is my oldest profile, but not the one with the most reputation for me.

Comment: I wish that display names and profile pictures for the different Q&A sites could ba managed from the main StackExchange Network profile, and not the other way around. As it is now, as you say, it is taken from the profile on the Q&A site you have most reputation on. To me at least, that doesn't seem logical at all.

Comment: Can you please check if it's oldest or most reputation? It can be quite misleading, to say the least